# Django Sign up redirect to last page not working

Tags: python, django, authentication, redirect

I want the user to be redirected to the last page after the signup form but it keeps redirecting to the homepage. I also have a login page that does redirection to the last page successfully and I'm trying to do the same with the signup. But as soon as I click the submit button after filling out the form, it just redirects to the index page

Here is the signup link

```
<li><a href="/signup?next={{ request.path }}">Sign Up</a></li>
```

signup.html

```
<h1> SIGN UP </h1>

  {% if user.is_authenticated and not user.is_superuser %}
      <h3>Hi {{ user.first_name }}. Thanks for loggin in!</h3> 
  {% else %}

  <form action="" method="post" id="user_uploader" enctype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %}
   {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                {{ field.errors }}
                {{ field.help_text }}
                {{ field }}
            {% endfor %}

   <p class="alert">By Clicking “Sign Up” below, you are agreeing to the Meddy <a href="/terms">Terms of Service</a> and <a href="/privacy">Privacy Policy</a></p>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" id="ss-submit">SIGN UP</button>
    </form>

{% endif %}
```

views.py

```
def signup_user(request):
    d = getVariables(request,dictionary={ 'page_name': "Sign up"})  
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            new_user = authenticate(username=request.POST['username'],password=request.POST['password1'])
            login(request, new_user)

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
        else:
            print form.errors

    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()

    d.update({'form': form,'usersignup':True})
    return render(request, "d1/signup.html",d )
```

Comment: i've added the views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot the redirect part in views.

```
#....
if form.is_valid():
   username = request.POST.get('username')
   password = request.POST.get('password1')
   new_user = form.save()
   new_user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
   login(request, new_user)

   # ------------------------------------
   if request.GET.get('next'):
      return HttpResponseRedirect(request.GET.get('next'))
   # ------------------------------------

   return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
else:
   print form.errors
#...
```